# How to fix mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlconnectattrs' threw an exception

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hi I am  trying to build a connection from visual studio 2019 / vb.net to phpmyadmin i try to follow tutorials in youtubes but i keep getting that error when im trying the connection i even try other verion of Mysql.Data

[image: Screencapture here]

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection("host=127.0.0.1; port=3306; username=root; password=; database=lab3")
        Try
            cn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thank you sir JayV

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by using this https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/1.3.2 :) hope it helps in the future!